# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-' (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I was trying to convert an array into an integer, and it should've been easy. But I've come up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Box Count (ongoing).py", line 32, in <module>
pixels = [map(int, x) for x in array]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

The problem is that i'm reading a file that's an ascii grid, that for a no_data value assigns a -9999 number ( it does so because in editing it's easier to target). So pretty much I could use a regex to change this values to another ones but I don't want to, so I'm wondering if it's just a gap in my code or if I'm not thinking this through. Can someone point out a solution?

Code:

```
im = open('input.txt', 'r')

imgx = 1452
imgy = 1916

array = []
with open("qqqf.txt", "r") as im:
    for line in im:
        array.append(line)

print array

pixels = [map(int, x) for x in array]
```

input file:

```
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 1 1 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
```

Comment: Your code expects each line to be one integer. If you have all the integers on the same line, you need to use `split()` to split it up into an array, and then loop over them.

Comment: does -9999 represent a negative or a possitive number with a - in front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got confused with `map` and list comprehension

```
pixels = [map(int, x) for x in array]
```

Here you take every element of `array`, name it `x` and then apply the function `int` to *every element in `x`*. But `x` is a string, and it's element are characters, so you end up applying the function `int` to `'-'`, then `'9'`, then `'9'` and so one…

What you wanted to do may simply be

```
pixels = map(int, array)
```

Also, if there is multiple numbers on each line of your file, you should change

```
array.append(line)
```

for

```
array.append(line.split())
```

Or you will end up with an array looking like `['-999 -999 -999', '-999 -999 -999']`

Comment: Beat me to it haha.  Your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The way map() works is that it applies the function (in our case int()) to every item in an iterable object (in our case, x which is a string) and returns a list of the results.  The mistake here is assuming that map will iterate over the array, but it's iterating over the string stored in x instead, because of

```
for x in array
```

The error occurs when you try to apply int() to the character "-".

Just use

```
map(int, array)
```

and be prepared to parse a nested list.